# Prove that $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}B$ if $A$ and $B$ are idempotent matrices and $I - (A+B)$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I've got a very interesting problem and wondering if my idea for the solution is right and complete. Please, take a look.

**Problem**

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$. Prove that $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}B$ if the matrix $I - (A+B)$ is invertible.

**Solution**

$A^2=A$

$B^2=B$

Let's subtract the second equation from the first one.

$A^2 - B^2 = A - B$

$(A - B)(A+B) = A - B$

$(A - B)(A+B) - (A-B)= 0$

$(A - B)((A+B) - I))= 0$

$(A - B)(I - (A+B))= 0$

Since $(I - (A+B))$ is invertible, let's multiply the above equation by $(I - (A+B))^{-1}$ from the right.

$(A - B)(I - (A+B))(I - (A+B))^{-1}= 0$

$A - B = 0$

Hence, $A = B$ which means that $rankA = rankB$.

Comment: No, $(A-B)(A+B)\ne A^2-B^2$ (unless $AB=BA$).

Comment: It is only true that $(A-B)(A+B) = A^2 - B^2$ if $AB = BA$.

Comment: There is an essential mistake in the second line: $(A-B)(A+B) = A^2+AB-BA+B^2 = A^2+B^2 +[A,B]$ if $[A,B]\neq 0$ the two terms don't cancle each other.

Comment: Any hints then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/985879/144766) that if $P$ is a projection matrix (matrix such that $P^2 = P$), it holds $\operatorname{rank} P = \operatorname{Tr} P$.

Notice that $A$ is a projection so  $I-A$ is also a projection. It follows
$$\operatorname{rank}(I-A) = \operatorname{Tr}(I-A) = n-\operatorname{Tr} A = n-\operatorname{rank} A$$

Now since rank is subadditive, we have

$$n = \operatorname{rank}(I-(A+B)) \le \operatorname{rank}(I-A) +  \operatorname{rank}(-B) = n-\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B$$
so $\operatorname{rank} A \le \operatorname{rank}B$.

By symmetry it follows $\operatorname{rank} B \le \operatorname{rank}A$ so we have equality.

Comment: Instead of using the trace, we could also note that $A(I - A) = (I - A)A = 0$, from which it follows that $\operatorname{im}(I - A)\subseteq \ker(A)$ and $\operatorname{im}(A) \subseteq \ker(I - A)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sure, but I wanted to arrive at $\operatorname{rank}(I-A) = n-\operatorname{rank} A$ without invoking linear maps (using only matrix-related tools).

Comment: +1, but I wonder how did you obtain that rank of $P$ = trace of $P$ "using only matrix related tools".

Comment: Thanks @mechanodroid for the answer, looks pretty fine. I've got a question though. Why is $n=rank(I−(A+B))$ ?

Comment: @RomanDryndik $I-(A+B)$ is invertible so it has full rank.

Comment: Oh, yes. I should have guessed. Thanks, @mechanodroid.

Answer (score 7):

As the comments explain, your current approach is wrong.

For one correct approach, try a proof by contrapositive. Suppose $A$ and $B$ do not have the same rank.  It follows that we have either
$$
\dim \ker (A) + \dim \operatorname{im}(B) > n
$$
or
$$
\dim \ker (B) + \dim \operatorname{im}(A) > n
$$
where $\ker(A)$ denotes the kernel (nullspace) of $A$ and $\operatorname{im}(A)$ denotes the image (column space) of $A$.

If the first condition holds, then $\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{im}(B)$ contains a non-zero vector $x$.  This vector $x$ satisfies $Ax = 0$ and $Bx = x$.  It follows that
$$
(I - (A + B))x = x - Ax - Bx = x - 0 - x = 0.
$$
That is, $I - (A + B)$ has a non-trivial kernel.  Thus, $I - (A + B)$ is not invertible.

If the second condition holds, we similarly conclude that $I - (A + B)$ has a non-trivial kernel and so cannot be invertible.

So, we have proven the desired result: if $I - (A + B)$ is invertible, then $A$ and $B$ must have the same rank.

---

A slicker approach is as follows: note that
$$
(I - (A + B))A = A - A^2 - BA = -BA\\
B(I - (A + B)) = B - BA - B^2 = -BA
$$
That is, we have
$$
(I - (A + B))A = B(I - (A + B)).
$$
If $(I - (A + B))$ is invertible, then multiply both sides by $(I - (A + B))$ from the left to conclude that
$$
A = (I - (A + B))^{-1}B(I - (A + B)).
$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are similar, we conclude that they have the same rank.

Comment: Thanks, @Omnomnomnom for the answer. I've got 2 questions related to both solutions. 1) If $x$ is a non-zero vector from $im(B)$ why it satisfies $Bx = x$?; as far as I understand mapping $B$ is $B: X \rightarrow Y$ where $X = Y$ is not necessary true? 2) Didn't get why you can conclude $A = B$ from the fact that $A = (I - (A + B) )^{-1} B (I - (A + B))$.

Comment: For 1: if $x$ is in the image of $B$, then $x=By$ for some vector $y$. It follows that $$Bx= B^2y = By = x$$

Comment: If $B$ is a mapping $B:X \to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are distinct, then $B^2$ no longer makes sense.

Comment: For 2: I don’t conclude that $A=B$, I conclude that $A$ and $B$ have the same rank because they are [similar matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).

Comment: Ok, now it's pretty clear. Thanks, @Omnomnomnom.