# If the trace of a matrix equals its rank, is it idempotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, trace, idempotents

It [is well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix#Trace) and [can easily be proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2345818/480910) that if a matrix $A$ is idempotent, then its trace equals its rank:

$$
A^2 = A \Rightarrow \mathrm{tr}(A) = \mathrm{rk}(A)
$$

Does the inverse also hold? If yes, how can this be proven?

Comment: Clearly not. Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0\\
0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, $\tr(A)=\rk(A)$ but $A$ is not idempotent

Comment: @AngaeMT you should post this as an answer

Comment: Another thing: I think you meant (as other responders also seem to agree) the _converse_ of the statement, not the _inverse_. The [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_(logic)) of this statement would be "if $A$ is not idempotent, then its trace and rank are unequal."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is $A$ is idempotent if and only if it has eigenvalues $0,1$, but the converse condition cannot ensure. So we can construct a counterexample with non-zero and non-one eigenvalues. For example, consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$which you can see $A$ has rank $2$ and $\operatorname{tr}(A)=2$, but $A^2\ne A$.

Answer (score 3):

The trace is linear, so we can achieve any desired value by simply multiplying $A$ by some scalar as long as $\operatorname{tr}(A)≠0$. For instance, $\widetilde{A}≔\tfrac{\operatorname{rk(A)}}{\operatorname{tr}(A)}A$ trivially satisfies $\operatorname{tr}(\widetilde{A}) = \operatorname{rk}(\widetilde{A})$.